# Не появляется ProgressBar

Tags: android, java

В цикле `while` вызывается процедура, в которой выполняется пост запрос. Но он очень долгий, поэтому, пока он выполняется, нужно чтобы крутился `ProgressBar`. Но у меня  при нажатии кнопки начинает выполнятся пост запрос, и черный экран, запрос выполнился и появились данные, а самого прогресс бара и в помине нет

```
[JAVA] public class KinoteatrActivity extends Activity {

private String[] TeatresIndex=new String[]{"1","190","6397","21141","32904",
        "23528","23287","22847","51598","51760","51764","51765","65487","65486","63470"};
private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.kinoteatr);

        int index=0;            
        int countTeatres=TeatresIndex.length;
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.loading);

        while (index!=countTeatres-1)
        {   
        index++;     
        String html ="<img src='http://topdekor.vot.by/"+PicturePath(index)+".jpg'/>";
        Spanned s = Html.fromHtml(html,getImageHTML(),null);
        Spanned stroka = Html.fromHtml(postData(index));
        if (index==countTeatres-2)
        {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        addToTextView(teatrName,stroka,s,count,index);       
        }[/JAVA]
```

Comment: Так как мне занести в поток post запрос, если  он находиться в отдельной процедуре, которая зависит от index который инкрементируется в while ???

Answer (score 2):

Крутилка должна быть в отдельном потоке, [пример](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/create-a-custom-progress-bar-using-asynctask)  прилагается.

Comment: Только не крутилка, а "тяжелый" запрос. Крутилка как раз таки должна быть в UI потоке. А не показывается она из-за того, он (UI поток) блокируется долгоиграющей задачей.

Comment: Точно ))))

Comment: вообще-то примерно начиная с андроид 2.1 запрещено выполнять любые синхронные операции с интернетом в главном потоке. Нужно создать класс, который наследуется от Thread, и переопределить в нем метод run()(для выполнения ваших запросов в нем)

Comment: extend AsyncTask(); лучше

Comment: Так как мне занести в поток post запрос, если он находиться в отдельной процедуре, которая зависит от index который инкрементируется в while ???

Comment: нече непонятно

Comment: class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Spanned , Void> {
  
      protected void doInBackground() {
          while (index!=countTeatres-1)
             {   
             index++;  stroka = Html.fromHtml(postData(index));
             publishProgress(stroka);
             }
          
          protected void onProgressUpdate(Spanned... spanned ) {
             addToTextView(teatrName,spanned [0]);  
         }
          
          String postData(int index) {
            
       }
      }
  
      }

Comment: String postData(int index) {
        
        String str = null;
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://topdekor.vot.by/api.php");           
           try {            
               List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
               nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("u", "android"));
               nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p", "03"));
...

Comment: ...
  
               HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
               
               str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
               response.getEntity().consumeContent(); 
                   str = str.replaceAll("<(.)+?>", "");
                   str = str.replaceAll("<(\n)+?>", "");
                
                      
           } catch (IOException e) {
            
            Log.e("ERROR","IOException");
           }
           return str;     
       }

Comment: наподобие вышенаписаного